# Oracle: Conditional not-null constraint when both conditions are true

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have to alter a table to create a conditional not null constraint on a specific column so that it cannot be null if col1 and col2 have values.

First, what is a conditional not null constraint?

Second, can you please provide a syntax on how to accomplish such thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The predicate you need to check is

```
if (col1 is not null and col2 is not null) then specific is not null
```

The predicate `if A then B`  can be writen as `not A or B`

Note that the precendence is `(not A) or B` see  the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2179261/263935)

So you get:

```
alter table spec add constraint my_spec
check (not (col1 is not null and col2 is not null) or specific is not null);
```

if col1 or col2 is null spcific is nullable

```
insert into spec(col1,col2,specific) values(null,null,null);
insert into spec(col1,col2,specific) values(1,null,null);
insert into spec(col1,col2,specific) values(null,1,null);
```

if  both col1 and col2 are defined secific in NOT NULL

```
insert into spec(col1,col2,specific) values(1,1,1);
insert into spec(col1,col2,specific) values(1,1,null);
-- ORA-02290: check constraint (REPORTER.MY_SPEC) violated
```

On existing table you can add this `check` only if the existing data fullfill the validation, otherwise you get this exception

```
 ORA-02293: cannot validate (OWNER.MY_SPEC) - check constraint violated
```

To find the rows that violated the new rule simply query

```
 select * from spec
 where NOT (not (col1 is not null and col2 is not null) or specific is not null);
```

You must either delete those rows or set `specific` to a non NULL value or set col1 or col2 to NULL.

**Alternatively** you may enable the constraint with `NOVALIDATE` option, this tolerates the existing violations, but enforce that new changes follow the constraint.

```
alter table spec add constraint my_spec
check (not (col1 is not null and col2 is not null) or specific is not null)
enable novalidate;
```

Comment: I tried executing the `alter` command but ran into the following error `an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.`

Comment: @samg added hint to your point, you must clean the data before enabling the constraint.

Comment: Or you remove the violations first from the table before add the constraint

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_specific
    check ( (col1 is null) or (col2 is null) or (specific is not null) );
```

This can also be written as:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_specific
    check (not ( (col1 is not null) and 
                 (col2 is not null) and
                 (specific is null)
               ) 
          );
```

If that helps you follow the logic better.

This evaluates to false only under the following conditions:

- `col1` is not null (i.e. `col1` does have a value)
- `col2` is not null (i.e. `col2` does have a value)
- `specific` is null

This is the exact condition that the OP wants to filter out.

On an existing table, you can see what rows violated the constraint:

```
select *
from t
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null and specific is null;
```

If any rows violated the constraint, you need to fix them before adding the constraint.

Comment: not sure how check works. But looks like `specific` cant be null if `col1` and `col2` are not null

Comment: Agree with @JuanCarlosOropeza, `specific` cannot be null if `col1` AND `col2` have values (not null).

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, thanks for the detailed answer. What will happen if `col1` and `col2` are null? In that case, there shouldn't be a problem correct?

Comment: @samg . . . If either `col1` or `col2` is `NULL`, then the `check` returns "true" and it passes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried executing the `alter` command but ran into the following error `an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.`